# Silverlight 4: how to show ToolTip on keyboard focus (revised)

Tags: silverlight, event-handling, keyboard, focus, tooltip

My original question:

Is there an easy way for a ToolTip to be shown when an item gets keyboard focus, not just mouse over? We have a list of items with tooltips that users will probably tab through, and the desired behavior is for a tooltip to be shown then too.

Added example XAML. A HyperlinkButton with the Tooltip set is what needs the keyboard focus as well.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="OfferingItemDT">
        <HyperlinkButton Command="{Binding Path=NavigateToLinkCommand}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Tooltip}">                
             <Grid x:Name="gOfferingButtonRoot" Width="275" MaxHeight="78" Margin="5,3">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Image x:Name="imgServiceOfferingIcon" 
                Grid.RowSpan="2"            
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Source="{Binding Path=Image, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImageConverter}}" 
                Stretch="UniformToFill" 
                Margin="2,10,0,0"
                MaxHeight="32" MaxWidth="32"
                />
                <TextBlock x:Name="txbOfferingTitle"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Text="{Binding Title}"                               
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"                                        
                    Style="{StaticResource OfferingTileTitleText}"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txbOfferingDesc"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Style="{StaticResource OfferingTileBodyText}"
                Text="{Binding BriefDescription}" />

             </Grid>
        </HyperlinkButton>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Updated:
Based on info in [WPF: Show and persist ToolTip for a Textbox based on the cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5917554/389809) as well as Anthony's comments, I tried this code in the GotFocus eventhandler:

```
        private void showTooltip(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HyperlinkButton hb = new HyperlinkButton();
        ToolTip ttip = new ToolTip();


        hb = sender as HyperlinkButton;


        ttip = ToolTipService.GetToolTip(hb) as ToolTip;
        ttip.IsOpen = true;            

    }
```

This seems like it would work, but ttip is always null. Help?

Answer (score 1):

"Easy" is subjective term.  Yes its easy.  On the same UI element on which you attach the `ToolTip` you can hook the `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` event handler the will use `ToolTipService.GetToolTip` to acquire the tooltip and the set `IsOpen` to `true` and `false` respectively.

Comment: Thanks. I am just the xaml guy so could use a little more help.

Comment: @dex3703: Thats shame because Stackoverflow is a place for developers.  Being a "Xaml guy" it would help if you included some Xaml in your question that I can use as basis for a more detailed answer.

Comment: I am on a large team and am trying to help out overwhelmed devs before code complete. Doesn't help that I've been away for several months. :)

Comment: Anthony -- just understood your suggestion and have posted code above. It's always null--what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The missing part is to define the tooltip in XAML so that we can access the Tooltip element.

```
<HyperlinkButton MouseLeftButtonUp="showTooltip">
  <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip>
      <TextBlock Text="My tooltip text"/>
    </ToolTip>
  </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
  <!-- ... -->
</HyperlinkButton>
```

Code behind

```
private void showTooltip(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  FrameworkElement frameworkElement = (FrameworkElement)sender;
  ToolTip tooltip = ToolTipService.GetToolTip(frameworkElement) as ToolTip;
  if (tooltip != null)
  {
    tooltip.IsOpen = true;
    frameworkElement.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(frameworkElement_MouseLeave);
  }
}

static void frameworkElement_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  FrameworkElement frameworkElement = (FrameworkElement)sender;
  frameworkElement.MouseLeave -= new MouseEventHandler(frameworkElement_MouseLeave);

  ToolTip tooltip = ToolTipService.GetToolTip(frameworkElement) as ToolTip;
  if (tooltip != null)
  {
    tooltip.IsOpen = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not able to check this now, and the project is long gone, but I'm sure it'll come up in the future.